# How to find the very last of the first elements of sequence which satisfy a given predicate in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to find the very last of the first elements of sequence which satisfy a given predicate, in Clojure.

I use the following code at the moment:

```
(last (take-while pred (gimme-potentially-infinite-seq ...)))
```

Unfortunately, `(take-while ...)` holds onto head, causing me out-of-memory in some cases.

I could you use `loop/if/recur` combo to solve that, but maybe there's some function (or combination of functions) in clojure.core that does exactly that?

UPDATE: it's not `take-while` which is holding onto head but `last`.

UPDATE 2: I tested this `(->> (range) (take 10000000) last)` in Clojure REPL and ClojureScript REPLs (Planck 2.0.0 and Lumo 1.1.0). There's major heap growth for Planck (2 GB of RAM) and Lumo (1.5 GB), while there's minor heap growth on the JVM (200-300 MB).

Comment: I may be missing something... but how can you expect to find the last element satisfying a predicate in an *infinite* sequence? You must scan the entire sequence to get the result.

Comment: Can you explain why you think `last` holds onto the head? Your invocation works for me with constant heap usage (no unlimited growth).

Comment: @glts it seems to be ClojureScript thing (see my update above).

Comment: You assume that the first element qualifies. Otherwise, you get `nil`. Is that satisfactory?

Comment: @Thumbnail yes, that's correct.

Comment: If you're confronting what looks to be a flaw in ClojureScript, why not resort to `loop`-`recur` to try to get round it? Have you tried? Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Just build it up slowly:

```
(def data (range 9999))
(defn is-evil? [x]
  (= 666 (mod x 1000))) ; is the number like xxxx666

(def all-matching-nums
  (filter is-evil? data))

all-matching-nums          => (666 1666 2666 3666 4666 5666 6666 7666 8666 9666)
(last all-matching-nums)   => 9666
```

Of course, the `filter` step will never terminate if your sequence is truly infinite.  That is another problem!

Comment: As I see it: The `filter` step always terminates - it's lazy. Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2766): the `lazy-sequence` macro captures its body as an un-evaluated function. If the filtered sequence is infinite, `last` does not terminate. Anyway, it's the last of the first maximal sub-sequence of compliant elements that's wanted; not the last compliant element of the whole sequence.